# Route an array of Routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my piece of code:

```
<Switch>
 {
   modules.map((m: any[]) => {
    m.map((subm, idx: number) => {
     return (<Route exact path={subm.routeProps.path} component={subm.routeProps.component} key={idx}></Route>)})})
 }
</Switch>
```

I'm not getting the routing correct, I guess because I have array of Route.

**modules** are a list of arrays (each module has some paths together)

Below is an example of a module (**Authentication**):

```
import Login from '../../components/login/login'
import SignUp from '../../components/signup/signup'

export default [
    {
        routeProps: {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login
        },
        name: 'Login'
    },
    {
        routeProps: {
            path: '/signup',
            component: SignUp
        },
        name: 'Sign Up'
    }
]
```

And the main exported **index.tsx** is:

```
import Analytics from './analytics'
import Dashboard from './dashboard'
import Games from './games'
import Users from './users'
import Authentication from './authentication'


export default [
    Dashboard,
    Analytics,
    Games,
    Users,
    Authentication
]
```

Comment: Please share an example of a `module` item, including the `ruoteProps`.  Also, explain what's wrong, or what error you're seeing to help us narrow it down.

Comment: Edited thanks. My question is how can convert that array to a list of react `Router` children

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the callback of your top-level `[...].map()`. Maybe that will solve your issue. (`modules.map((m: any[]) => { /**/ return /**/ m.map((subm, idx: number) => [...]`.) Or simply remove the curly braces.

Comment: Yes that's the right answer, could you please put it as an answer, it may be of help for others. Thanks